# HTML Input in hindi

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to take input from forms in hindi language as the user types in the form field in kruti dev style. So what changes i need to make in my input tag such that it takes input in kruti dev font.

Comment: If you want your visitors to see the Kruti Dev font, you need to make it available via `@font-face`

Comment: yes using @font-face I resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to achieve. All your user needs to do is have hindi enabled as a keyboard through your their settings. Then when you select the hindi keyboard you can type in the input box. To set the input box to default hindi you can use the lang attribute on the input.

Comment: i want to have a input element exactly like when changing font in MS Word to kruti dev and then typing. Like i want to type text in kruti dev fonts

Comment: Then you need to use the lang attribute on your input